# Asignar nombre a variables en MySQL2 en Execute

Tags: javascript, mysql, typescript, prepared-statements

Estoy haciendo una Query con MySQL y TS, entiendo que para evitar la inyección SQL hay que enviar los parametros por aparte de la consulta, el detalle es que veo que solo se usa el signo ? y el orden de los parametros para asignarlos, entonces si hubiera una falla en el orden de los parametros sería un gran problema, hay alguna forma de pasar nombrados dichos parametros?, Gracias!

```
const queryString = "SELECT * FROM bd.tabla WHERE id > ?;"; //Hay alguna forma de nombrar el parametro en lugar de solo pasar el signo "?"  ?

    const params = [10];

    const [rows] = await pool.execute<IUser[]>(queryString, params);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo solucioné, por si alguien le sirve, estoy usando TypeScript, primero al crear la conexión o el pool, en las opciones hay que habilitar el `namedPlaceholders` de la siguiente manera:

```
const pool: Pool = await mysql.createPool({
        namedPlaceholders: true,....
   });
```

Después solo hay que agregar dos puntos (:) en los parametros de la query y pasar los datos como un objeto simple:

```
const params = {id: 1};
const query= "SELECT * FROM bd.tabla WHERE id > :id;";

const [rows] = await pool.execute<IUser[]>(query, params);
```